# If x is even, then x is not divisible by 5.

Tags: logic

I have to provide a counterexample otherwise. So if one counterexample is enough, can I say x=10, because 10/5 = 2, thus x is not divisible by 5. Is this a justifiable answer?

Comment: Yes.${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Well, you should conclude that x *is* divisible by 5, so the proposition is false.

Comment: yes, that is a good counterexample.

Comment: It is a good counterexample.  I'd just say $10$ is even (clear); $10$ is divisible by $5$ (clear); so if $x=10$ then $x$ is both even and divisible by $5$.  So the statement is false.

Comment: wow that was fast, this website rocks!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, if you have a logical statement $A$, which is stated as valid, then it is assumed to be true under all interpretations. However, if there exists one interpretation, call it $x$ for which $A(x)$ is false, then $A$ is not valid.

And, you have demonstrated this in your example. The statement $A := $" If $x$ is even, then $x$ is not divisible by $5$" was assumed to be valid, yet for $x = 10$,  $A(10) :=$"If $10$ is even, then $10$ is not divisible by $5$" was false. Therefore, by contradiction, $A$ is not valid. I.e. You have chosen a counterexample.

Comment: I got this other statement that seems similar to my eyes and I have to provide a counterexample if it is false. It says: 

Every even integer is not divisible by 5.

Can i use the same counterexample as the one above?

Comment: @Joe Looks like it doesn't say a whole lot!

Comment: yeah woops, missclicked lol!

Comment: @Joe Although theses questions are related, you might want to think about posting a different question which asks for similarities and differences between the two semantic statements.

Comment: @Joe Yes, the same example works, but I still think your question(s) are about phrasing and logical equivalence.

Comment: Okis! thank you for your heavenly help! :)

Comment: wot? im new here, what do u want me to do

Comment: oh ok nevermind! got it! :)

Comment: @Joe Thank you! It helps the community if the answers have been "closed out".

Comment: of course, whatever i can do to help, since u helped me out! :) have a great and amazing day